# Nested List Question: changing variable that the list take without changing the list itself

Tags: python

I have a problem regarding the nature of the nested list. When I tried to change the variable assigned to it, it was also changed. Why does this happen? I would appreciate any help finding a way around this.

```
x = list();
y= [1,2,3,4] 
x.append(y)
print x   #return [[1,2,3,4]]
del y[-1]
print x   #return [[1,2,3]
```

Comment: It happens because `x.append(y)` doesn't copy `y` it just adds a reference to `y` to the list. After the append `y` and `x[0]` are the **same** list.

Comment: You should copy the list, so for example `x.append(y[:])`.

Answer (score 0):

newlist.append(list(oldlist)) should do the trick as well.

Answer (score 0):

> When I tried to change the variable assigned to it, it was also changed.

You're not changing variables there. `del y[-1]` does nothing to the variable `y`, it does something to the object (list) denoted by `y`. (As opposed to `del y`, which really does delete the variable `y`.)

> Why does this happen?

Because `y` is an (only) element of `x`. The fact that you append it to `x` doesn't change `y` in any way. It is still the same object.

> I would appreciate any help finding a way around this.

It depends on what do you want behavior to be. If you want "value semantics", that is, for `y` to be copied when appending it to `x`, just say so:

```
x.append(y.copy())
```